# Recurrence Relation for QuickSort

Tags: recurrence-relations

Suppose a special recurrence relation for quicksort is: 
 $T(0)=\Theta(1)$
 (N>0) $T(N)= T(N-1)+T(0)+\Theta(\sqrt{N}) $

How does this relate to the theta class of: $\Theta(N \sqrt{N})$ ?
Can someone please help me understand why this takes place and the steps it takes to get their?

Answer (score 0):

If
$T(N)= T(N-1)+T(0)+\Theta(\sqrt{N})
$,
then there are positive constants
$a$ and $b$ such that
$a\sqrt{n}
<T(n)- T(n-1)-T(0)
< b \sqrt{n}
$.

Summing this from
$n=2$ to $m$,
$\sum_{n=2}^{m} a\sqrt{n}
<\sum_{n=2}^{m} (T(n)- T(n-1)-T(0))
< \sum_{n=2}^{m} b \sqrt{n}
$,
and,
since
$\sum_{n=2}^{m} \sqrt{n}
\approx \frac12 m^{3/2}
$,
we get
$ T(m)-T(1)-(m-1)T(0)
=\Theta(m^{3/2})
$
or
$ T(m)
=\Theta(m^{3/2})
$.